# python:error in user input and concatenate string

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python I'm trying to accept input from user and concatenate the strings but it's giving invalid syntax error

```
devicename = raw_input("Please enter devicename: ")
ip = raw_input("Please enter ip ")
print "create ltm node ", devicename, "address ", ip
```

Comment: you missed one comma after `devicename` in line 3

Comment: you are missing a comma. The last line shoud read `print "create ltm node ", devicename, "address ", ip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to concatenate with **+** mark like this:

```
print "create ltm node "+devicename+"address "+ip
```

Answer (score 2):

I missed the comma after device name. The line should be read print "create ltm node ", devicename, "address ", ip

Comment: You may close the question

Answer (score 0):

print "create ltm node ", devicename ,"address ", ip
you missed a comma after devicename